# File Can be accessed fwhile running jnlp but cannot be accessed through browser in java web start

Tags: file, jar, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm trying to access a resource file which is in a jar file deployed in `apache web server`.
The file can be accessed through the jnlp file in the deployed folder while but it is not available through the web start while trying to access from a browser.

The code used to access the file using the uri is something like below :

```
File helpFile = new File("/myFile.doc");
```

`myFile` is in the application `jar` deployed in the server.

Answer (score 0):

A JNLP application is running locally on your machine so it will have 'file' access to the Apache web server. You have to access it with [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or any of the RESTful client API.

Furthermore, to access file locally on your server, you have to use the [FileOpenService](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/CRC/documentation/jdk1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#FileOpenService) not File.